# How to Develop on a Mac and Test on IIS

Tags: macos, web-development-server

I'm using a Mac for web development, and have a business requirement to use IIS for my web server. I'd like to be able to test my code in IIS before committing and deploying my code to the production server.

I know I could run a VM (I've used Parallels, VMWare Fusion and Virtual Box in the past). The downside is that this uses memory & processor power from my Mac.

Is there an easy way to watch my development folder and automatically copy new/changed files from the Mac to the test server running IIS? Are there any issues around file owner/permissions on Windows for these files? I know IIS can be persnickety sometimes about serving files if the permissions are incorrect.

Basically, I want to avoid running Windows/IIS on the Mac. So what are my options?